# ENV variables within cloud run server are no accessible

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, nuxt.js, google-cloud-run

So,

1. I am using NUXT
2. I am deploying to google cloud run
3. I am using dotenv package with a .env file on development and it works fine.

I use the command `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` within my dev server on Nuxt and it works great, I make sure that the .env is in git ignore so that it doesnt get uploaded.

However, I then deploy my application using the google cloud run... I make sure I go to the Enviroments tab and add in exactly the same variables that are within the .env file.

[image]

However, the variables are coming back as "UNDEFINED".

I have tried all sorts of ways of fixing this, but the only way I can is to upload my .env with the project - which I do not wish to do as NUXT exposes this file in the client side js.

Anyone come across this issue and know how to sort it out?

DOCKERFILE:

```
# base node image
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /user/src/app

ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Copy local nuxt code to the container
COPY . .

# Build production app
RUN npm run build

# Start the service
CMD npm start
```

Kind Regards,
Josh

Comment: Please include your `Dockerfile` and a minimal example so we can attempt to reproduce.

Comment: Added my docker file for you!

Comment: I would just like to add that i tried doing:

ENV PL_APP_SECRET=123

and 

ENV PL_APP_SECRET 123

Within the docker but still had no luck!

Comment: Do you have something that load a dotenv file and write the value as env var? If so, is this process clean all existing env var is dotenv file doesn't exist?

Comment: i have this at the top of my nuxt config .js? const env = require('dotenv').config() could that be it?

Comment: UPDATE: Removed that from the build - It still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of code of how you are assigning the variables and using the "dotenv"?

Comment: Have you tried setting the environment variables through the command line? For example --set-env-vars "KEY1=VALUE1", you can see more detail on the official documentation: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

I was using Nuxt v1.11.x
From version equal to or greater than 1.13, Nuxt comes with Runtime Configurations, and this is what you need.

in your `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
       BASE_URL: 'some'
    },
    privateRuntimeConfig: {
       TOKEN: 'some'
    }
}
```

then, you can access like:

```js
this.$config.BASE_URL || context.$config.TOKEN
```

More details [here](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config)

Answer (score -1):

To insert value to the environment variables is not required to do it in the Dockerfile. You can do it through the command line at the deployment time.

For example here is the Dockerfile that I used.

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

this is the app.js file

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port = 8080

    app.get('/',(req,res) => {
        const envtest = process.env.ENV_TEST;
        res.json({message: 'Hello world',
                  envtest});
    });

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`))
```

To deploy use a script like this:

```
gcloud run deploy [SERVICE] --image gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE] --update-env-vars ENV_TEST=TESTVARIABLE
```

And the output will be like the following:

```
{"message":"Hello world","envtest":"TESTVARIABLE"}
```

You can check more detail on the official documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables#command-line